# Java--how to create multiple animated geodesic lines with google maps

Tags: animation, line

--I'm brand new to coding, but slowly working my way through fiddles. Your patience is appreciated!--

I'm working on creating a visual representation of the diaspora of a small village in Ukraine. I have so far found a fiddle that does what I need, up to a point. I'm having trouble with the following bits though:

- I have no issue with a single var departure --> var arrival line animating, as per the original fiddle, but I can't quite find resources on how to add another line (whether same var departure or different).
- I would also like to add multiple points along the same itinerary. Everything I've found uses a list of LatLng coordinates but I can't get that to animate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/bz4b9jkg/6/

```js
var map;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.142556, -42.219561);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas').get(0), myOptions);
var departure = new google.maps.LatLng(49.461686, 23.174658); //Set to whatever lat/lng you need for your departure location
  var arrival = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6983279,-74.0433196); //Set to whatever lat/lng you need for your arrival location
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [departure, departure],
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    geodesic: true, //set to false if you want straight line instead of arc
    map: map,
  });
  var step = 0;
  var numSteps = 250; //Change this to set animation resolution
  var timePerStep = 5; //Change this to alter animation speed
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    step += 1;
    if (step > numSteps) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(departure, arrival, step / numSteps);
      line.setPath([departure, are_we_there_yet]);
    }
  }, timePerStep);
  line.setMap(map);

});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
body{padding-top:25px;}
#map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&dummy=.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
           <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```